# How to use bootstrap v4 scss version in bower project

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, bower

I have been using SASS/SCSS version of bootstrap #3.3.6 but now in the bootstrap site they say they release version 4 now.

Everywhere I am getting how to use bootstrap v4 (non scss) in any project but I am not getting anywhere how to use the scss version of bootstrap v4 in bower project.

Bootstrap moved completely from less to scss and it will be great to use the scss version of the new bootstrap with lot of new features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my bower.json i include it by following:

```
"dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "v4.0.0-alpha.6",
}
```

then just include the bootstrap.scss in your main.scss, possibly you have to adjust the path to your bower_components folder.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ bower install bootstrap#v4.0.0-alpha.2
```

You can see the full information regarding using bower to get bootstrap 4 here: http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/download/